# useSelector hook and rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

-- edit -- i created a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hofstadter-d3jjo

I'm starting to scratch my head and would like some help on - I assume - a simple problem.

I have a basic App component that renders a controlled text input. Once you submit this input it creates a message on the back-end, which updates a redux store. Everything seems to be working fine on this part.

My issue is when I tried to add a `useEffect` hook to reset the input value after a new message was added. I noticed that the `useEffect` that relies on `[messages]` is called on every render instead of just when `messages` changes. The simple act of typing in the input - which causes a rerender for every character - makes the hook trigger, even though it is still the same value: an empty array.

Basically I've noticed it only works as intended if my `useSelector` returns the same instance of an array. So if I were to read only `state.messages.allIds` it would work since the array does not change. But simply adding a `.map(x => x)` makes it return a new instance every time.
I have added react-redux's `shallowEqual` to try and fix this, but to no avail, and I don't understand why it doesn't fix my problem.

```
const App = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const messages = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => (
      state.messages.allIds.map((id: string) => state.messages.byId[id])
    ),
    shallowEqual,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect');
  }, [messages]);

  // ...

  return (
    <form onSubmit={/* ... */}>
      <input
        onChange={event => setMessage(event.target.value)}
        value={message}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe coming pretty late. But it might benefit others facing the same problem.

If you do not want the function to re-render on state change and only want to extract the value of a redux state variable, you may use useState

```
const state = useState();
const yourVariable = state.getState().reduxStateVariable;
```

Comment: It's `useStore()`, not `useState()`.. useState hook is (usually) a hook from the base React package. Redux has the useStore hook.